# progress dialog deactivating while reverting back

Tags: android, progressdialog

i have created a progress dialog when i go from login page to home page it show with message login successful but if i come back from home page to login page than alsoo progress dialog show i want to dismiss this method when i come back 
 i know dismiss.progressbarname() one method is there but were to put this i am not getting can anyone please tell me

Comment: Your Statement : "i have created a progress dialog when i go from login page to home page it show with message login successful", You are using progress dialog for what ?. Seems from your statement that you are displaying message login successful in progress dialog. ?

Comment: ya i am displayin login successful

Comment: What do you actually want to do ?.. ProgressDialog is used for telling the user that some background process is working. And when that process gets over, dismiss it and show the result (Another Activity or Toast(for testing purpose)).

Comment: i wanted to display progressdialog til the background process is working and when it get response thn progressdialog gets over and i moved to another Activity......

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776236/how-to-implement-a-progressdialog-while-activity-requests-a-soapobject-from-a-web

Answer (score 0):

put it to `onKeyDown()` of your activity method in switch statement on case, where key code is `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`.